# Calling Custom Assembly Attributes

Tags: vb.net, .net-assembly, getcustomattributes

I have created a custom attribute and use it in the AssemblyInfo.vb file.  The attribute is declared in another file like so:

```
Public NotInheritable Class AssemblyBuildNameAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Private _p1 As String

    Sub New(p1 As String)
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _p1 = p1
    End Sub

End Class
```

And is in the AssemblyInfo.vb file like so:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.4.15")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("13.10.1.8")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyBuildName("alpha")>
```

How can I call this custom attribute?? I would like to be able to call it just like I call the version information like so:

```
Public Class AppInfo
  Public Shared Function VersionMajor() As String
    Return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Major.ToString()
  End Function
  Public Shared Function VersionMinor() As String
    Return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Minor.ToString()
  End Function
  Public Shared Function VersionPatch() As String
    Return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Build.ToString()
  End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Reflection to get attribute information and value,  and you will need one proc for each attribute.

First though, your sample Attribute class is missing a key item: HOW TO RETURN the info.  You need to add a property getter:

```
Friend ReadOnly GetBuild() As String
   Get
      Return _p1
   End Get
End Property
```

NOW you are ready

```
Friend Function GetAsmBuild() As String
    Dim assy As [Assembly] = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim Attributes As Object()


    Attributes = assy.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(AssemblyBuildNameAttribute), False)
    If Attributes.Length > 0 Then
        Return Attributes(0).GetBuild
    Else
       Return String.Empty
    End If

 End Function
```

`GetVersion` is the name of the Property getter.  So for the one I added it would be:

```
Return Attributes(0).GetBuild
```

It is about the same as getting Attr for Classes or Enums etc.  Also: Assemblies already have a version and such you can control in the Project properties settings.  And procs already exist in `System.Reflection` to return them.

**Edit:**

The way to get the info at runtime:

```
Public Shared Function VersionPatch() As String
    Return GetAsmBuild
 End Function
```

or name my proc `VersionPatch`

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for.  However in the AssemblyInfo.vb (the default file that stores assembly info), I want to be able to add "<Assembly: AssemblyBuildName("alpha")>" to the bottom of the file and have the GetAsmVer to return the string "alpha"

Comment: Then all you really need to do is add one custom Attr and runtime reflection getter like the one above.  You'd actually be better off adding custom attr to something like a small, empty Ver class (ie a file YOU own) in your project and getting them just about the same way rather than tinkering with a file that VS may update/overwrite.  Oh, I understand what you are doing...I updated the example to address the whole GetBuild thing.  Comments in code and above, still valid though.

Comment: This returns "Nothing" is it because I need to define the AssemblyBuildNameAttribute and <Assembly: AssemblyBuildName("alpha")> in the same file?

Comment: No.  You can actually set the Asm attr in your main class file, it doesnt have to be right next to the VS controlled VS attr.  Did you add the prop getter? and use that exact name in the return?  And I have to ask WHAT returns nothing - that will tell you if it is a prob with the Attr, getter or function to retrieve the attr value. (Breaks can be set in all that code.

Comment: NVM I got it to work I copy pasted what you have here an poof for some reason it works.