# Custom Assembly Attribute to String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, .net-assembly

I have defined a custom assembly attribute and am trying to call it into a string much like my previous post [Calling Custom Assembly Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127737/calling-custom-assembly-attributes). I am now trying to accomplish the very same thing in c#.

I have defined my custom attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;

namespace authenticator.Properties
{
    public class SemverAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private string _number;

        public string getversion
        {
            get {return _number;}
        }

        public SemverAttribute(string Number)
        {
            _number = Number;
        }
    }
}
```

And am attempting to call it with:

```
// Define the semver version number
Assembly assy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object[] attr = null;
attr = assy.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SemverAttribute), false);
if (attr.Length > 0)
  {
    ViewBag.Version = attr[0].getversion;
  }
else
  {
    ViewBag.Version = string.Empty;
  }
```

However when trying to build I get:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'getversion' and no
>   extension method 'getversion' accepting a first argument of type
>   'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need a cast, as `Assembly.GetCustomAttributes(xxx)` return type is `Object[]`

so

```
ViewBag.Version = (attr[0] as SmverAttribute).getversion;
```

EDIT

this could be rewritten like that (for example)

```
var attribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                        .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                        .OfType<SemverAttribute>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

ViewBag.version = (attribute == null)
                  ? string.Empty
                  : attribute.getversion;
```

Comment: Is there any easier way to accomplish this other than my attempt and your solution?

Comment: @aaronmallen not sure about what you mean by "easier", see edit maybe ?

Comment: Would this be deemed more efficient or better practice?

Comment: @aaronmallen it's rather a choice of readability... I wouldn't say one is better than the other (and efficiency is not the problem here)

Comment: what would be the problem? Would you not recommend doing this via custom attribute?

Comment: @aaronmallen oh, I didn't mean there was a problem. Just saying that you won't have efficiency problems with one or another method to retrieve these attributes.

Comment: Thanks more questions on the same subject here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52519/return-custom-assembly-attribute-variables would love to hear your input.